# GDAL 1.9.1 ogr2ogr KML to PostGIS not incuding ExtendedData

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I have a KML file utilizing a Schema in the document and ExtendedData in each placemark. The ExtendedData does not seem to pass in conversion to PostGIS or shapefile.

Answer (score 3):

The default KML driver does not handle extended data tags, you need the LIBKML driver.

Comment: The LIBKML driver is incorporated in GDAL Version 1.9.2 onwards, OSGEO4W packages, MS4W and Qgis Master.