# Importing KML in QGIS - what are all the node elements that QGIS looks for other than Name and Description?

Tags: qgis, kml, ogr2ogr

Of all elements given at (ref: http://service.kmlvalidator.com/ets/ogc-kml/2.2/) only Name and Description seem to be recognized on importing KML using QGIS 1.8.0-Lisboa. I would like to know if this is completely true or few other elements from the spec are also recognized?

My question is related to the two below:

1. [GDAL 1.9.1 ogr2ogr KML to PostGIS not incuding ExtendedData](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32363/gdal-1-9-1-ogr2ogr-kml-to-postgis-not-incuding-extendeddata)
2. [How to convert KML to shapefile without losing attributes using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33826/how-to-convert-kml-to-shape-file-without-losing-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

Import from kml with ogr2ogr can use either kml or libkml. You can read the specifications here:
http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_kml.html
http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_libkml.html
Everything not mentioned there will not get imported.

UPDATE:

The LIBKML driver is incorporated in GDAL Version 1.9.2 onwards, OSGEO4W packages, MS4W and Qgis Master.